# Hard Drive Keeps Corrupting Important Files, Need New Hard Drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

I'm using Ubuntu MATE and fairly frequently I will try to boot my computer only to be faced by some "rescue mode" or failure screen from which I follow online guides which direct me into updating and replacing certain files (usually ones with /sda/dev in their name) until it's fixed and I can access my computer again.

This has happened multiple times and I am getting tired. Is this due to my hard drive being old and crappy or is it something wrong with Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be a bad stick of RAM. Run a memory test.

Comment: [Check your hard disk for problems](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en). Post your SMART data for analysis.

Comment: I did a SMART analysis yesterday and saved the output as a libre document but now I can't get into my PC to see this file (drops me into some 'grub' recovery mode), if I boot off of installation medium am I able to access this file?

Comment: I did a SMART analysis yesterday and saved the output as a libre document but now I can't get into my PC to see this file (drops me into some 'grub' recovery mode), if I boot off of installation medium am I able to access this file?

Comment: Usually yes. There is still the faint possibility that it's some other part of the computer that is failing, although the disk stays as prime candidate.

Comment: @harrymc Currently away from my computer, when I get back to it, if I manage to find the SMART analysis would it be possible for me to pm it to you?

Comment: It would be best to upload it to some website like pastebin and post the link here.

Comment: @harrymc https://pastebin.com/G8jqZ3gc

Answer (score 1):

According to the SMART data, your disk is having issues.

The attribute
[Current Pending Sector Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9133)
means that 75 disk sectors have errors but couldn't successfully be
recovered and mapped to healthy spare sectors.
I assume that these are the same 75 bad sectors reported by the attribute
Offline Uncorrectable.

With uncorrectable errors on the disk, my advice is to quickly backup your data
and then replace the disk.
If you can't boot from this disk, use a Linux live CD/USB.